# метод concat в конструкторах на прототипе Array

Tags: javascript, ооп, concat

Не понимаю поведение метода concat в конструкторах на прототипе Array; это БАГ или что ( ?

пример:

```js
/* 1. 
   создали конструктор на прототипе Array. 
*/  
var MyArray = function(){}
    MyArray.prototype = new Array(); 
/* 2.
   объявляю переменную "myarr" и присваиваю ей свойства конструктора "MyArray()" через оператор "new";
*/
var myarr = new MyArray();
/* 2.p.s.
   т.к. конструктор MyArray() является наследником всех свойств конструктора Array() через свойство "prototype", ожидаю что унаследованы методы будут вести себя (правильно)
*/
/* 3.
 используя метод "push" добавил пару значений
*/
 myarr.push(2,3);
/* 4.
 а вот метод concat ведёт себя не естественно
   4.1
 вместо того, чтобы создавать новый массив Array из заданных участков, он создает массив Array с ссылками на свойства переменой "myarr"
*/
var myarr_c = myarr.concat(myarr); 
  myarr.push("A");
console.log(myarr_c);

/* пример на простом Array */
//2.
var arr = [];
//3.
   arr.push(0,1);
//4. 
var arr_c = arr.concat(arr);
   arr.push("A");
console.log(arr_c);
```

**Как понимать такое поведении конструктора "MyArray" ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что происходит:

```js
var o = { prop: "value" };
var push = [].push;
var concat = [].concat;
push.call(o, 123);
console.log(o);
console.log(concat.call(o, [1,2,3]));
```

`myarr` получил методы массива, но массивом не является. Выведите `typeof myarr`.

Comment: так чего не хватает конкату чтобы выдрать массив из объекта. ведь он именно это и должен делать, почему он просто оставляет ссылку, что его останавливает ?

Comment: и что я должен получить typeof ? -- object